# Benefits of jq grid over mvc web grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I am using mvc web grid in an mvc application but i also want to use jq grid will it be more suitable than web grid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you asked i can simply answer as JQGrid because we know although web grid have strong capability but jqgrid is customisable . So it extends its strength.